# Having loaded and installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 My Display is very large

Tags: resolution, display

My Screen on my Acer Aspire 7720 is giving me problems so I use a digital TV make SABA this screen works ok at resolutions up to 1024 x 768 with windows vista, 7, and windows server 2012.

But when I run Ubuntu It detects a CVT 46 inch monitor and gives me a display of over 2560 x  Basically I can't change it in settings as I can't get everything in the window and I can't select what I need to reduce the picture size.

How do I sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

simply, in the upper-right, click on the power button and click `system settings`, select `displays` and then choose your display and configure the right resolution you want